# Selecting data from two different tables of the same database in PHP/ MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I have 2 different tables **SECTION** and **SUBSECTION** in a database **QUIZ**. The **SECTION** table has 2 columns **section_id** and **section_title**, whereas **SUBSECTION** table has 4 columns **section_id**, **subsection_id**(AI), **subsection_title**, **subsection_detail**. Now, what I want is that the **section_title** but the table that needs to be queried is the **SUBSECTION** table and with the help of the **section_id** from the **SUBSECTION** table we would have to fetch the **section_title** from the **SECTION** table.

I have tried some of the solutions given over here but I don't know why these aren't working for me. Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `IN` in a way that the results from one query can be passed to another.

Perhaps this is an idea:

`SELECT section_title FROM section WHERE section_id IN (SELECT section_id FROM subsection WHERE [some condition here to get the correct set of ids from subsection table])`

Comment: could you please explain the later part after the WHERE clause?

Comment: That would be condition that you use to query in the subsection table. I imagine it may be something similar to `subsection_id = 'some-id'`, or `subsection_title = 'some-title'`. Though, it is good to mention that the later one may return multiple results, as opposed to the first, which queries by id and is intended to return one single result only.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. It will select the section_title and everything from the subsection table.

```
SELECT section.section_title, subsection.* FROM section, subsection WHERE section.section_id = subsection.section_id
```

Add this to return a specific section:

```
AND section.section_id = $id
```

Comment: could you take care of the syntax and type over here again the exact query as I am having some problem again.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this is the correct and working command.
`SELECT section.section_title, subsection.* FROM section, subsection WHERE section.section_id = subsection.section_id AND section.section_id = $id`
Obv. replace $id with the actual id.

Comment: this worked for me
$SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT section_title FROM section WHERE section_id IN (SELECT section_id FROM subsection WHERE subsection_id = '$THEORY_DI')";